# android: MultiAutoCompleteTextView style like gmail

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I want create custom MultiAutoCompleteTextView like gmail app:
[image]

I create custom view and extend to MultiAutoCompleteTextView and use Span , but I have problem, if there is not enough room for text and image then and span have (space) then view split them

[image]

and there is my code for custom view:

```
public class CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView extends MultiAutoCompleteTextView {

@Override
public void setTokenizer(Tokenizer t) {
    super.setTokenizer(t);
}

public CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


@Override
protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar);
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append("g");
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getContext(), getRoundedBitmap(bitmap)),
            builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
    builder.append(text);
    builder.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 1, builder.length(), 0);
    super.replaceText(builder);

}

public static Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = Color.RED;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    bitmap.recycle();

    return output;
}


}
```

So any body have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Check these two libraries:

- [kpbird/chips-edittext-library](https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library)
- [splitwise/TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

They are doing pretty much what you try to accomplish.

The idea behind at least first library - once `onTextChanged` happens, you do create a `Bitmap` out of `TextView` with text and setting `CompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` (drown on the `Canvas`).

> ```
>           TextView textView = (TextView) lf.inflate(R.layout.chips_edittext, null);
>             textView.setText(c); // set text
>             int image = ((ChipsAdapter) getAdapter()).getImage(c);
>             textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, image, 0);
>             // capture bitmapt of genreated textview
>             int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
>             textView.measure(spec, spec);
>             textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(), textView.getMeasuredHeight());
>             Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>             Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
>             canvas.translate(-textView.getScrollX(), -textView.getScrollY());
>             textView.draw(canvas);
>             textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
>             Bitmap cacheBmp = textView.getDrawingCache();
>             Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
>             textView.destroyDrawingCache();  // destory drawable
>             // create bitmap drawable for imagespan
>             BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
>             bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0,bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
>             // create and set imagespan 
>             ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable),x ,x + c.length() , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
> ```

Once the image+name is just one bitmap - it can't be no longer wrapped and your issue is solved.

Comment: @Kaonstantin tnx for suggestion lib, I saw them before but these lib is not suitable for me.

Comment: @MehrdadFaraji I don't mean to use them, I just suggest to use same principle: draw your image+text on the Canvas, then convert to the Bitmap and use as an ImageSpan. Easy!